# How to traverse nested data

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, lodash

I have to traverse a large data set to collect the final child element of the nodes in javascript.

I need to end up with an array of the Branch Codes found in the child Details.
Here is the output I'm attempting to get:

[1000, 1201, 1202, 2101, 3101, 3201]

```js
{
  "TITLE": {
    "FirstLevel": {
      "Details": {
        "Code": "01",
      },
      "SecondLevel": [
        {
          "Details": {             
            "Description": "{desc}",          
          },
          "ThirdLevel": {
            "Details": {
              "Code": "01",
            },
            "FourthLevel": [
              {
                "Details": {
                  "Code": "11",
                },
                "Branch": {
                  "Details": {
                    "Code": "1000",
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "Details": {
                  "Code": "12",
                },
                "Branch": [
                  {
                    "Details": {
                      "Code": "1201",
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "Details": {
                      "Code": "1202",
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Details": {
            "Code": "100",
          },
          "ThirdLevel": [
            {
              "Details": {
                "Code": "02",
              },
              "FourthLevel": {
                "Details": {
                  "Code": "21"
                },
                "Branch": {
                  "Details": {
                    "Code": "2101",
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "Details": {
                "Code": "03",
              },
              "FourthLevel": [
                {
                  "Details": {
                    "Code": "31",
                  },
                  "Branch": {
                    "Details": {
                      "Code": "3101",
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Details": {
                    "Code": "32",
                  },
                  "Branch": {
                    "Details": {
                      "Code": "3201",
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at answers on more basic questions and tried to adapt the solution.

One such solution takes in an id passed, and will update the name based on the id. I thought I could use the similar map implementation here. There is an issue because the array doesn't just have 'children' to represent where there will be child nodes.

```js
function update(object, passedId) {

    object.children.map((element, index) => {
        if (element.id === passedId) {
            console.log(index)
            object.children[index].name = "New Name"
        }
        if (element.children != null) { // condition for checking Nesting
            update(element, passedId)
        }
    })

    console.log(object.children)
}

update(obj, "Branch");
```

Next I tried a more simple approach

```js
function getSubItem(obj) {
  for (item in obj) {
    for (subItem in obj[item]) {
      for (subsubItem in obj[subItem]){
      console.log(obj[item][subItem][subsubItem]);
      }
    }
  }
}
getSubItem(obj)
```

and so on, adding sub after sub after sub item, but that kind of nested for looping seems incredibly unstable, and since branches can be nested in different areas it doesn't seem reliable either. Am I missing an easy solution here?

Comment: add expected result

Comment: @stasovlas Here is the output I'm attempting to get:

[1000, 1201, 1202, 2101, 3101, 3201]

Comment: My edits to your question are intended to help you understand how to write good questions and to help you understand the real issue. Both are intended to help you get a good answer more quickly. Repeatedly removing those edits is bad SO etiquette and destructive to your own cause.

Comment: @JAAulde Sorry about that, I only noticed your edits after doing my own-- I honestly thought I must have missed things and put them back in, didn't realize they were edits of someone else. Once I realized that I found your edit about what constitutes JSON helpful

Comment: Right on. I’m sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: i think the structure should be optimized cause FirstLevel is an object  and SecondLevel is an array.can you optimize the data?

Comment: @xianshenglu let me look into it... I think it comes back as an array if there is one result and an object with multiple, or the other way around. I'll see if I can optimize but I think it comes to me dependent on the number of children.

Comment: array is more reasonable even there is only one result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
function update (data, passedId, acc = []) {
    if (!_.isObject(data)) {
        return acc;
    }

    return _.reduce(_.values(data), (result, item) => {
        result = _.chain(item)
            .get(passedId)
            .thru(val => [val])
            .flatten()
            .compact()
            .map('Details.Code')
            .thru(vals => _.concat(result, vals))
            .value();
       return update(item, passedId, result);
    }, acc);
}

const res = update(data, 'Branch');
```

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_lodash___default.a.concat is not a function at the line:           .thru(vals => _.concat(result, vals))
do you know what that could be?

Comment: attempting to run using JSFiddle to isolate the code but getting Unexpected identifier error : https://jsfiddle.net/xt3san8d/

Comment: The error had to do with my version of lodash, when I upgraded, the error went away

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
const obj = {
    "TITLE": {
        "FirstLevel": {
            "Details": {
                "Code": "01",
            },
            "SecondLevel": [{
                    "Details": {
                        "Description": "{desc}",
                    },
                    "ThirdLevel": {
                        "Details": {
                            "Code": "01",
                        },
                        "FourthLevel": [{
                                "Details": {
                                    "Code": "11",
                                },
                                "Branch": {
                                    "Details": {
                                        "Code": "1000",
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Details": {
                                    "Code": "12",
                                },
                                "Branch": [{
                                        "Details": {
                                            "Code": "1201",
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Details": {
                                            "Code": "1202",
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Details": {
                        "Code": "100",
                    },
                    "ThirdLevel": [{
                            "Details": {
                                "Code": "02",
                            },
                            "FourthLevel": {
                                "Details": {
                                    "Code": "21"
                                },
                                "Branch": {
                                    "Details": {
                                        "Code": "2101",
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Details": {
                                "Code": "03",
                            },
                            "FourthLevel": [{
                                    "Details": {
                                        "Code": "31",
                                    },
                                    "Branch": {
                                        "Details": {
                                            "Code": "3101",
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "Details": {
                                        "Code": "32",
                                    },
                                    "Branch": {
                                        "Details": {
                                            "Code": "3201",
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

function transData(data, propertyName, path, result = []) {
 
    if (data instanceof Array) {
        data.forEach(obj => transData(obj, propertyName, path, result));
    } else if (data instanceof Object) {
        let existProperty = Object.keys(data).indexOf(propertyName) > -1;
        if (existProperty) {
            getCode(data[propertyName], path, result);
        } else {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => transData(data[key], propertyName, path, result));
        }
    }

    function getCode(data, path, result) {
        if (data instanceof Array) {
            data.forEach(obj => getCode(obj, path, result));
        } else {
            if (typeof path !== 'undefined') {
                result.push(path.split(/\./g).reduce((accumulator, val) => accumulator = accumulator[val], data));
            } else {
                result.push(data);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(transData(obj, 'Branch', 'Details.Code'));
console.log(transData(obj, 'Branch'));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as I changed the names of the Levels to 'FirstLevel', 'SecondLevel' etc. for the question but actually their names are something like, 'Division1', 'AccountingSystem' etc. so they are not consistent. Is there a different way to traverse down the levels?

Comment: @jenryb have updated the code , this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try [_.eachDeep](https://deepdash.io/#eachdeep-foreachdeep) method from Deepdash (deep Lodash extension).

Here is your case:
https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/moMpLV

```
var res = [];
_.eachDeep(data,function(value,key){
  if(key=="Branch"){
    if(!_.isArray(value)){
      value = [value];
    }
    _.each(value,function(v){
      if(v.Details&&v.Details.Code){
        res.push(v.Details.Code);
      }
    });
  }
});
```